# symmetric matrix , an orthonormal basis for V is $\{XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{1},...,XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{n}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ vector space, $Q$ is symmetric  matrix and positive definitive, it decomposes $Q=XDX^{T}$ yields an orthonormal basis for $v$ given by the scaled columns of $X$, namely, $\{XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{1},...,XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{n}\}$.

My attempt:
I know if $Q$ is symmetric, then is diagonalizable, there exists a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $Q$, but I don't know how it looks like that$\big(\{XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{1},...,XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{n}\}\big)$, it's very general. Any help to proof, thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you clearly stated what the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the question you are trying to answer is something like the following:

> Let $V$ be the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, let $Q$ be a symmetric and positive definite matrix . Noting that $Q=XDX^{T}$ for some diagonal $D$ and orthogonal $X$, **show that** $\{XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{1},...,XD^{^{\frac{-1}{2}}}e_{n}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$ (consisting of scaled columns of $X$) **relative to the inner product** induced by $Q$.
>
> *(The **bold** portions indicate information missing from the original question)*

With this in mind, we need to verify the following: for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$, we have
$$
\langle XD^{-1/2}e_i,XD^{-1/2}e_i \rangle_Q := 
(XD^{-1/2}e_i)^T QX(D^{-1/2}e_i) = 1\\
\langle XD^{-1/2}e_i,XD^{-1/2}e_j \rangle_Q := 
(XD^{-1/2}e_i)^T QX(D^{-1/2}e_j) = 0.
$$
It is straightforward to show that the above holds if we use our decomposition $Q = XDX^T$ and the fact that $X^TX = I$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, that was my question.
Rather another question if you could help me, if i have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(XD^{-1/2}e_{i})(XD^{-1/2}e_{i})^{T}=XD^{-1}X^{T}$, why it is $XD^{-1}X^{T}$ and not $nXD^{-1}X^{T}$